# Excel Lenovo Dropdown without VBA

Tags: excel, formula

Are there any ways to add lenovo dropdown in one cell based on what user put in this cell without VBA?

For example, dropdown options: {"abc","bcd","cde"}, if user input "a", then dropdown will be "abc" only.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want a searchable drop down list and that without VBA. There can be two ways your search will take place
either
it will filter all data having a which I feel is a better option
OR
you just want to check if the fist character of ur data starts with a which is very simple by checking =left(text,1)="a" test.
But that is just the logical test involve. The real challenge is to should know how u can create a named dynamic range which only will pave ur way to searchable drop down. U said to avoid VBA. The video m referring to is without VBA.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8z1g1mqXyrk